# Ionic2 + Backand + Twitter social signin not working?

Tags: ionic2, backand

I am currently using Backand to power an Ionic2 app, so far so good...

I tested social signin a good few months back and all appeared to be working fine, however as of late they seem to be failing.

Google+ - announce they are no longer supporting webview oauth, the backand documentation still points to a soon to be deprecated installation method? (No ios support now?)

Facebook - seems to be working fine - good job.

Twitter - for some reason just does not work no matter what I do, I have followed the documentation step by step, created my app in twitter - added a phone number, I even disabled my app to leave the standard "backand" twitter authentication and it still failed, i'm using the backand-ionic2-starter here.

https://github.com/backand/backand-ionic2-starter/blob/master/src/providers/backandService.ts

Anyone else experiencing the same issues or have an alternate social signin solution for backand?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing these issues out. We have a bug in our SDK that is preventing social signin from functioning properly. We're working on the fix, and it should be included with our next SDK release. Please stay tuned, a fix should be forthcoming - keep an eye on the github repo at https://github.com/backand/vanilla-sdk.